# Extract the outer points of a Point Shape into a Line Shape?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, line, concave-hull

I've installed QGIS 2.8.2 since a few days and have no experience with this application. I try to extract the outer points of a Point Shape into a Line Shape, like a shell for the inner points. All points of the shape has to be in or on the border of the line.

Is there any possibility or function in QGIS, to do this ? (see figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHzaI.jpg) below)

[image]

Comment: Did you have a look at "convex hull"? The result will be larger than in your example but it may already be what you are looking for depending on the use case.

Comment: Hi Matthias, thank you very much for your help. Indeed the result is rough, but it seems to be the function i was looking for.

Comment: The result seems to be a polygon layer, can i convert this one into a line layer? Thanks, Grimey

Comment: A polygon is the better option in many cases (handy for future analysis), maybe you just need to go to symbology and set the fill to transparent. Or you can do http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15819/how-can-i-transform-a-polygon-to-a-linestring-in-qgis

Comment: Polygons to lines is simple translation in the tools section.

Comment: There is also a concave hull plugin which might give a better result. Install with plugin manager and you will find it from the Vector menu.

Comment: Related/duplicates: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113084/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119663/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131537/